# Oscova custom entities issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bots, entity, chatbot

hi i am working on **oscova** to build an assistant type of bot.I followed there [tutorial](https://developer.syn.co.in/tutorial/bot/oscova/unity-bot.html) and everything was great but [template mode](https://developer.syn.co.in/tutorial/bot/oscova/entity-recognizer.html) was not working and I want to capture input **"search xyz"** or **"open xyz"** .Everything after  a **search or open** I want to capture so that I can search it on internet or open that app .I made a entities with name **command** and gave **search** and **open** in it .Then to capture the rest input I made a **custom entity with a regex** that capture every thing after **command** .But now when I ask "how are you " it captures that too and send it to my function intent .See my code and help please

```
    public class searchEntity : IEntity
{
    public searchEntity() { Type = "query"; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
public class queryRecognizer : IEntityRecognizer
{
    public string EntityType => "query";

    public EntityCollection Parse(Request request)
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"\s[|a-zA-Z|\s]*");
        var entities = new EntityCollection();
        foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(request.NormalizedText))
        {

            var entity = new searchEntity
            {
                Value = match.Value,
                Index = match.Index
            };
            Debug.Log(entity.Value);
            entities.Add(entity);
        }

        return entities;
    }
}
```

**###This is where I am using these entities###**

```
public class BotFunctions : Dialog
{
   
    [Expression(" {open} @query")]
    [Expression("{youtube} @query ")]
    [Expression("{search} @query ")]
    [Expression("please {open} @query")]
    [Expression("please{youtube} @query ")]
    [Expression("please{search} @query ")]
    [Expression("{youtube} @query please ")]
    [Expression("{open} @query please")]
    [Expression("{search} @query please ")]
    [Expression("{ar gallery}")]
    [Expression("{ar cinema}")]
    [Expression("{screenshot}")]
    [Entity("command")]
    [Entity("query")]

    public void userfunction(Context context, Result result)
    {
     
        var searchQuery = result.Entities.OfType("command");
        var funtionQuery = result.Entities.OfType("query");
        
        string word1;
        if (searchQuery.Value.ToLower() == "open")
        {
            result.SendResponse("Opening app");
            word1 = funtionQuery.Value.Trim();
            OpenApplications(word1);
        }
        else if (searchQuery.Value.ToLower() == "search")
        {
            result.SendResponse("starting search");
            word1 = funtionQuery.Value.Replace(' ', '+');
            word1 = word1.Substring(1);
            Debug.Log(word1);
            SearchInternet(word1);

        }
        else if (searchQuery.Value.ToLower() == "youtube")
        {
            result.SendResponse("starting youtube search");
            word1 = funtionQuery.Value.Replace(' ', '+');
            word1 = word1.Substring(1);
            Debug.Log(word1);
            searchyoutube(word1);
        }
        else if (searchQuery.Value.ToLower() == "ar gallery")
        {
            result.SendResponse("starting AR Gallery");
            OpenARGallery();
        }
        else if (searchQuery.Value.ToLower() == "ar cinema")
        {
            result.SendResponse("starting AR Cinema");
            OpenARCinema();
        }
        else if (searchQuery.Value.ToLower() == "screenshot")
        {
            result.SendResponse("Taking ScreenShot");
            TakeScreenShot();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `@query` and then explicitly marking it as an entity with `[Entity ("query")]` is invalid. When you specify an entity name with @ that entity must be defined by an [entity recognizer](https://developer.syn.co.in/tutorial/bot/oscova/entity-recognizer.html).

If you're trying to capture some arbitrary text you should use [@sys.text](https://developer.syn.co.in/tutorial/bot/oscova/system-entities.html#generic) entity following some concrete words

#### Simple Example

`Open App @Sys.Text` - Will match ***open app notepad***

Comment: can you give an example of @sys.text with some concrete word?

Comment: @TahaHussain Have added an example for you.